# How to create SMS app in salesforce

Tags: app

can i know how can i send SMS to management user from salesforce.
the details that needs to be send in message is:
1)Leads generated of the previous day
2)vehicle sales information.
3)Dealer Wise sales chart.

I want to know is this a paid app from app exchange or is thier any possibility of getting free apps with this service.

Comment: sravya you can integrate SFDC with twilio for this requirement .

Comment: The charging model for SMS services is usually per message sent where you add credit to an account that each send debits. You should Google to find the possible companies (Twilio is one) and check their pricing and features. If they don't have code to help with the calling from Salesforce but do have a web services API (usually a REST one) you could build/get built Apex code to call it (using [HttpRequest](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm)) as the API is usually simple (e.g. https://www.plivo.com/docs/api/message/).

Comment: There are numerous apps on the app exchange that also do SMS provided you use their service.  You may want to look at some of those as well, especially since it appears you primarily are only looking for outbound messaging. There's at least one or two that offer bulk SMS messaging.

Answer (score 1):

Existing free apps you may want to look at would include [AppShark Open SMS](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5RVSEA3) and [xSMS](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003JHeXEAW). Generally speaking, you'll need to have or create an account with an SMS gateway provider and can expect usage charges to be applicable on a per-message basis.

Comment: That second link (xSMS) takes me to a question.  I think it's probably intended to be this? https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003JHeXEAW

Comment: @Jagular I've edited my answer to use the link you've provided. Mine was obviously incorrect. I don't recall xSMS having been a private listing at the time I wrote this answer, but at the moment, I also can't find it in my Bookmarks from the App Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any development skills you and install twilio for Salesforce and acheive this with some very simple triggers.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/salesforce/install

I use it in my org on numerous custom objects and send around 5000 SMS's a month.

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Daniel. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference, giving credit to the author. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. If you will, please update your answer with more information.

Comment: Well I guess that's the last time I come on here. That mindset is bonkers. Why would I rewrite something that is continually changing/developing. By doing that when my link is updated my content/answer will not be and so someone finding this question looking for answer in 3 years will get out of date information. Still with a link for an application helper library built by a company that is a leading provider of SMS services.

Comment: I suggest you visit the [Help] to better understand the SF.SE model. It's very well possible this site may not be a good fit for you. This site is self-moderated and "link-only" answer are frequently voted for removal. Your post was in the review queue. I didn't realize until just now that I'd also responded in this thread as only your post and the original question was visible in the queue at the time I commented.

Comment: It would be a better answer with a simple example of how twilio is used, even if it is very basic.